# Woocommerce variable product short description tags not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Okay,

So on the simple product short description, you are able to use html tags and codes like 
 and so on. But when I try to do that with variable product short description it does not work.. I need to get this https://gloriblends.com/product/capsules-dream-sleep/

When you click the 7 Days to say 
Ingredient: all on this line and as follow
then
Coupons Excluded From This Product - this needs to be on another like otherwise it looks very bad. But anytime i use 
 it does not work

Maybe the only way to do this would be to create a php script in the variable product php file? I am not sure

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the code below in your active child-theme's functions.php

```
foreach ( array( 'pre_term_description' ) as $filter ) {
    remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_filter_kses' );
}

foreach ( array( 'term_description' ) as $filter ) {
    remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_kses_data' );
}
```

The code above will tell WooCommerce to stop stripping the HTML.

Always put custom code in the child-theme, otherwise you will lose your edits when the theme updates.

Hope this helps.